# How to use same setstate method to set state of different variables to true / false using react?

Tags: reactjs

I have to set the state to `true` or `false` based on certain conditions. I have the state defined in parent component and I set its state to `true` or `false` by calling a method from child component.

Below is the code,

```
class ParentComponent extends React.purecomponent {
    state = {
        first: false,
        second: false,
    };

    set_first_to_true =() => {
        this.setState({first: true});
    }

    set_first_to_false =() => {
        this.setState({first: false});
    }

    set_second_to_true =() => {
        this.setState({second: true});
    }

    set_second_to_false =() => {
        this.setState({second: false});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ChildComponent 
                set_first_to_true={this.set_first_to_true}
                set_first_to_false={this.set_first_to_false}
                set_second_to_true={this.set_second_to_true}
                set_second_to_false={this.set_second_to_false}/>)
     }
 }

 class ChildComponent extends react.purecomponent {
     componentDidUpdate () {
         this.props.set_first_to_true();
         this.props.set_first_to_false();
         this.props.set_second_to_true();
         this.props.set_second_to_false();
     }
}
```

Now as you see from above code, there is duplication of code. how can I refactor this such that there is no repetition? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse one state update handler like this:

```
// Parent

...
handleUpdate = (name, value) => {
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
};

...
render() {
  return (
    <Child onUpdate={this.handleUpdate} />
  );
}

// Child

...
this.props.onUpdate('first', true);
this.props.onUpdate('first', false);
this.props.onUpdate('second', true);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

define:

```
changeState = (stateName, Value) => this.setState({[stateName]: Value})
```

use in child:

```
changeState('first',true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is passing a correctly bound callback to parents setState. Other answers do the same, but they miss the binding.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      first: false,
      second: false
    };
    this.setStateRemote = this.setStateRemote.bind(this)
  }

  setStateRemote(item){
    this.setState(item)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent setParentState={this.setStateRemote}
      />
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.props.setParentState({first: true})
    ...
}
```